# Общий механизм взаимодействия с бд

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, оптимизация, activerecord

Решил написать проект (учебный) на laravel.  И так как это известный фреймворк естественно посмотрел как он устроен. 
Конкретно интересовала реализация механизма:

- работы c базой данных
- сессий
- CSRF

Сейчас меня интересует общий вопрос по базам данных.

Посмотрев пару фалов реализации работы с базой данных для себя понял следуюющее:

- в файле конфигурации хранятся данные для подключения к базе данных; и выбрано драйвер.
- так как реализована поддержка множества известный бд, то и написаны классы которые выполняют подключение ( возвращают объект PDO) с учетом специфики каждой бд (MySQLi - файл ; MySQL - сокет / удалено) и т.д.
- после чего реализован общий интерфейс работы с бд ( общая грамматика SQL ), соответственно и реализован этот интерфейс для каждой бд с учетом их специфики работы. ( поддержка транзакций и т.д. )

Сам принцип взаимодействия с бд построен по шаблону [ActiveRecords](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveRecord), с этим ясно так так такой принцип и в других фреймворках ( тот же Yii ).

После чего у меня возник вопрос: если на каждую таблицу создана модель, то как тогда делать сложные запросы? ( запросы с подзапросами, соединение таблиц и т.д.).

Посмотрев документацию Laravel нашел ответ на свой вопрос [здесь.](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/queries)

Бегло посмотрев примеры кода, опять таки видно что есть класс обвертка который по сути занимается тем, что генерирует sql.

Если что-то понял не так, пожалуйста исправте, именно для этого и создан этот вопрос.

И на основе всего выше сказанного сами вопросы:

1. В чем преимущество использования ActiveRecords кроме того, что каждое свойство объекта соответствует названию столбца в таблице бд?
2. Есть множество книг по оптимизации работы баз данных ( к примеру Шварц Б., Зайцев П., Ткаченко В. и др. - MySQL. Оптимизация производительности), по SQL в которых тоже есть много "умного" по правильной работе с тем же NULL  т.д, нормальные формы бд... Тогда почему не пишут SQL? Не спорю удобно написать один раз код где-то и потом использовать везде, но что насчет оптимизации?
3. У каждой бд своя специфика работы, поддержка как стандартизированных функций так и нет ( тот же MySQL). Опять таки написано уйму книг по их настройке и оптимизации. Тогда правильно ли все сводить к одному общему интерфейсу? Как по мне тогда нет никакого смысла использовать что-то лучше чем MySQLi для блога и MySQL для крупного проекта. (Имею введу поддержку Oracle бд, это мощная бд, ресурсоемкая, но ее использовать будут для вставки и обновления)

Comment: Я сам с ORM работал, но слышал мнение, что ORMы придумали для того, чтобы не учить SQL. В этом их главное (а возможно, и единственное) преимущество.

Comment: Просто так мир устроен. 80% разработчиков на php sql нормально не знают и не хотят знать. О производительности то же думать уже не принято. Делается все для ускорения разработки. а как оно будет потом работать это уже дело десятое. По этой причине я никогда и близко не подхожу к использованию подобных генераторов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveRecords` - это `ORM`.

**Преимущества отсюда очевидные:**

1) Независимость от СУБД. (т.е. если БД у вас сменится на тот-же постгрю, то не надо будет переписывать).

2) ООП подохд.

3) Связи, валидация, удобство работы и куча других мелочей.

**Недостатки офк тоже есть:**

Если опустить всякие аргументы типа, больше времени нужно, памяти и т.д. то главный минус это то, что паттерн нарушает некоторые другие, например: `Принцип единственной ответственности`. Так-же могут быть лишние запросы, но это уже второстепенное.

**P.S.:**

В принципе вы все описали. Так работает `ActiveRecord`, в целом, он удобен при разработке. Про оптимизацию нечего сказать ибо ничего конкретного вы не спросили, `ActiveRecord`, как и любая `ORM` не гарантирует оптимальность `SQL`-запроса но `99%` зависит именно от вас. От того как вы составите запрос с помощью `ActiveRecord` и настроите БД.

**P.S.2:**

Если вам не нравится `ActiveRecord` используйте `DataMapper`. Надо понимать, что `Laravel` хочет стандартизировать свои проекты, а за любым стандартом кроется куча камней и минусов (всем не угодишь). Для очень нагруженных сайтов, возможно `ORM` не используется, но чтобы так нагрузить, надо еще постараться.

Comment: "ActiveRecord, как и любая ORM не гарантирует оптимальность SQL-запроса но 99% зависит именно от вас. От того как вы составите запрос с помощью ActiveRecord и настроите БД.".

Полностью согласен с этим. 

Что касается "Про оптимизацию нечего сказать ибо ничего конкретного вы не спросили", спрашиваю:

- Как правильно выполнить тестирование схемы базы данных на определение узких мест если буду использовать ORM? (составление теста; сделать замер скорости выполнения до оптимизации и после и т.д.)

 Или все же это лучше делать отдельным инструментом?

Comment: @Владимир Возьмусь уточнить что именно тестировать? если тупо сами запросы, то все таки я рекомендую использовать отдельные инструменты, у ActiveRecord другая задача, для тестирования он не сильно предназначен, хотя скорость и прочие мелочи должен предоставлять. Оптимизация это вообще отдельный процесс, нельзя их совмещать. В двух словах: вы отдельно тестируете, ищите оптимальный запрос, для вас, а потом его транслируете на activerecord